# Interposing on OSX, my function not being called

Tags: c, macos, interposing

So, I'm messing around with some interposing code on OSX (gcc 4.2.1) and I'm trying to get the following to work:

When I call ./login using the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=my.dylib, it should override the default login implementation and use my custom implementation. Granted this is a contrived example, but its just to help me understand the point.

My source:

> cat libinterposers.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "login.h"

typedef struct interpose_s
{
  void *new_func;
  void *orig_func;
} interpose_t;

int my_open(const char *, int, mode_t);
int my_close(int);
int my_login();


static const interpose_t interposers[] __attribute__ ((section("__DATA, __interpose"))) = 
{
     { (void *)my_open,  (void *)open  },
     { (void *)my_close, (void *)close },
     { (void *)my_login, (void *)login },
};

int my_login()
{
  printf("--> my_login()\n");
  return 1;
}

int my_open(const char *path, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
  int ret = open(path, flags, mode);
  printf("--> %d = open(%s, %x, %x)\n", ret, path, flags, mode);
  return ret;
}

int my_close(int d)
{
  int ret = close(d);
  printf("--> %d = close(%d)\n", ret, d);
  return ret;
}
```

> cat login.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "login.h"

int login()
{
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  if (login() == 1)
  {
    printf("login successful\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("login failed\n");
  }
}
```

And finally, login.h

```
int login();
```

Now when I execute with something like "cat /dev/null" it works fine ...

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/tmp/libinterposers.dylib cat /dev/null
--> 3 = open(/dev/null, 0, 0)
--> 0 = close(3
```

However, when I run with my ./login example

```
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/tmp/libinterposers.dylib ./login
login failed
```

As you can see, it just prints login failed, my custom "my_login" function never runs ... any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `login` function is linked statically, not dynamically, so there's nothing to interpose.  You can't interpose statically linked functions.  If you want this to work, you'll need to move `login` to its own dynamic library.